# Issue with my Angular2 code

Tags: javascript, angular

**1**. I have several buttons on the same page, as you can see below:

[image: Add button]
[image: Add button] [image: Add button]

**2**. Once any of them clicked it shows the below button

[image: added]

**The issue:**

I have a page that contains several **ADD** buttons like in (**1**), if I click on the first button (then it shows the incrementing/decrementing button like in (**2**) which is totally normal). Then, if I click the second, third.... **ADD** button, (the incrementing/decrementing button **(2)** disappears from other buttons even if I already incremented/decremented values in that button).

**The code:**

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="#item of list">
  <div *ngIf="currentEl === list">
    <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="button" (click)="dec(elem)" value="Down"/>
         <input type="text" #elem value="0"/>
         <input type="button" (click)="inc(elem)" value="Up"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </div>
   </div>
  <div (click)="addTo(list)" *ngIf="currentEl !== list">ADD</div>
```

JS:

```
 let list = ["Banana", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Milk"];


export class App {
     //THIS IS THE ADD BUTTON
       addTo(element){      
          this.currentEl = element;
       }

    inc(elem)
    {
      var nItem = parseInt(elem.value);
      if(nItem < 5)
      {
        nItem +=1;
        elem.value = nItem;
      }
    }

    dec(elem)
    {
      var nItem = parseInt(elem.value);
      if(nItem > 0)
      {
        nItem -=1;
        elem.value = nItem;
      }
    }
  }
```

What should I do to solve the issue?

Comment: What is `currentEl`? What values does it have, how and where is it updated?

Comment: I've done an edit, please check the content of addTo() function in the JS part.

Comment: I guess it should be `this.currentEl = element;`?

Comment: That's true! I just made a mistake in copy/pasting the code from my code editor, anyway, I corrected it.

Comment: I guess the issue is that you refer to the same property for each `<tr>` created by `*ngFor`. In `*ngIf` use use the same `currentEl` (`=== list)`. But I have to admit I didn't fully understand what you try to accomplish.

Comment: I guess because of the same issue, and I don't know how to refer to an `id` for example. In JavaScript, we can select by id name (i.e `document.getElementById("demo");`) I guess if I do the same in angular2 it should solve the problem. However, can you please tell me which part of the issue that's not clear for you?

Comment: Actually I'm quite unsure about all of it ;-) What is the expected behavior?

Comment: The expected behavior is that if I click `add button`, it should keep showing the new `incrementing/decrementing` button, even if I click on the other `add` buttons. What's going on now is that, once I click the first add button, it switches to the other `incrementing/decrementing` however, if I click on other add buttons, it undo the other `incrementing/decrementing` to their original state which is `add button` in other words, I can't have more than one `incrementing/decrementing` in my page.

Comment: Hello Folky, Are you trying to built an application with cart that contains fruits? Are you trying to add/remove items from the cart ? can you give a little more details of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

I've assumed you are trying to implement a cart with items. Please see below for implementation.

```js
//our root app component
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <b>Items:</b>
    <div *ngFor="#item of list">
      <label>{{item.name}}</label>
      <div *ngIf="hasItem(item)">
          <tr>
             <td>
               <input type="button" (click)="dec(item)" value="Down"/>
               <input type="text" [value]="item.total"/>
               <input type="button" (click)="inc(item)" value="Up"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
       </div>
      <button (click)="inc(item)" *ngIf="!hasItem(item)">ADD</button> 
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div>
    <b>My Cart:</b>
    <div *ngFor="#item of list">
      <label>{{item.name}}</label>: <span>{{item.total}}</span>
    </div>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
   list = [{name: "Banana", total: 0},
            {name: "Apple", total: 0},
            {name: "Kiwi", total: 0},
            {name: "Milk", total: 0}];
   
  //THIS IS THE ADD BUTTON
    inc(item)
    {
      item = this.list.filter(obj => obj.name === item.name);
      var nItem = parseInt(item[0].total);
      if(nItem < 5)
      {
        nItem +=1;
        item[0].total = nItem;
      }
    }

    dec(item)
    {
      item = this.list.filter(obj => obj.name === item.name);
      var nItem = parseInt(item[0].total);
      if(nItem > 0)
      {
        nItem -=1;
        item[0].total = nItem;
      }
    }
    
    hasItem(item) {
      console.log(this.list.filter(obj => obj.name === item.name)[0].total);
      return this.list.filter(obj => obj.name === item.name)[0].total > 0;
    }
    
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

complete implementation is in the Plnkr code: https://plnkr.co/edit/2SZCQoyMi5aOZpjYB4sL?p=preview